# Can I have a fallback for peerDependencies?

Tags: npm, dependency-management, package.json

In my package.json I want to declare a peerDependency and provide a fallback, if the user of my package does not have this peerDependency installed.

I have stumbled upon this repeatedly and I cannot seem to find a good solution. Let's assume, I am the author of a library that consists of two npm packages, where one packages depends on the other:

- `package1`
- `package2` => has dependency to `package1`

In order to achieve the fallback behavior I tried adding `package1` as a dependency as well as a peerDependency to `package2`.
Unfortunately it seems that this completely ignores the peerDependency, because peerDependencies do not enforce any behavior, they just yield a warning.

I am considering to remove the dependency, just leaving the peerDependency, which will force the user to install both packages, when they want to use `package1`, which I would like to avoid.

Is there any clean way to achieve the mentioned behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading quite a bit about this, there is no clean way to achieve this (as expected quite frankly).

One blog post, that I found useful was [this one](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/). In my case to increase compatibility I will most likely resort to just using a peer dependency and sacrifice a bit of usability.